# How did Madara know that Sasuke is the last surviving Uchiha?

Tags: naruto

**SPOILER ALERT: If you haven't read Chapter 657 of the manga, read further at your own risk.**

In Chapter 657, the reborn Uchiha Madara asks Sasuke to join his side, remarking that they are the last of the Uchiha. However, he died before the Uchiha clan massacre, and was reincarnated with Edo Tensei only during the fourth World War. He fought with the five Kages, and then headed to the battlefield where Obito was fighting Naruto's team. Obito didn't have a chance to tell him the story of what happened after his death.

How come he knows that Sasuke is the last surviving Uchiha?

[image: Madara asking Sasuke]

Comment: Zetsu told him :)

Comment: Uhm, yeah, I did think of it, but I read through the chapters again, and there wasn't any time when they could chat.

Comment: @Happy, I think the question is "how he knew" instead of "why he knew". Nevertheless, as an *ultimate* Uchiha, he will search for his clansmen and as a result, he then gain information of what really happened to them.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Of course, Madara still might not know about the Uchiha massacre. All he needs to know is that the only Uchiha alive are Sasuke, Obito, and himself.

Comment: He may knew it by Zetsu imbued by his will. They can communicate to each other even they were apart so far.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru You are right, Madara doesn't necessarily know of the Uchiha incident. I removed that statement from the title, even though it is a little inaccurate now. I really didn't want to write the title as "How did Madara know that all other Uchiha besides himself, Obito and Sasuke are dead?" Tobirama would be furious at such a long title, so please bear with it. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In pages 11, 12 and 13 of chapter 657, it is clear that Madara and Black Zetsu (Madara's will) are able to communicate with each other:

[image: Page 11 of chapter 657]

Black Zetsu adds (in page 11) that both him and Madara were underestimated. And in the two pages that follow, he 'shows us' flashbacks in which him and Madara have been communicating during the war.

Given this, **I'd say it's safe to assume that Madara got the information from Black Zetsu**:
Either because he told him everything directly; or Madara may have gotten the information 'instantly' as soon as he was revived, since Madara and Black Zetsu share a deeper bond, since the latter is the former's will.

Answer (score 4):

I figure two possible solutions:

1. Zetsu told him
2. When absorbing Hashirama's chakra and gaining access to Sage Mode, he can identify people's chakras further allowing him to determine if any of the shinobi in the vicinity are Uchiha

Keep in mind, Madara basically made Sage Mode look like a joke in almost every aspect possible :)

EDIT : Or perhaps we can call this a plothole :S
I should also add that maybe Madara doesn't know about the Uchiha massacre, but rather just knows that he and Sasuke are the only Uchiha alive (excluding Obito because of his situation).

Comment: I very much feel that it was the 1st of the reasoning that you gave. Black Zetsu is Madara's will, which is very much an integral part of Madara. Madara and Zetsu have been shown to communicate with each other over large distances, so maybe sometime after madara was revived using edo tensi zetsu gave him an idea of the current scenario. Though this has not been mentioned in the manga and is only my speculation, but it kind of fits into the puzzele. :)

Comment: @debal Both seem very valid. It takes 2 seconds for Zetsu to say that the only Uchiha alive is Madara Sasuke Obito. On the other hand, Sage Mode is more than enough to identify other Uchiha as well.

Comment: @kirikara, it is possible that sage mode allowed him  to know that, but saage mode has a range of sensing right? Beyond a range he can't sense chakra, so what happens if the Uchiha's were alive and they were sent to some far off place for what ever reason. Does madara presume that Uchiha's are dead just because only he and sasuke is present in the battlefield. :) (Naruto did ask Tsunade, since he can't sense Kakashi's chakra was he out of the village on some mission)

Comment: That is possible, but one can always assume that all Uchiha would be participating in this shinobi war, and if they are injured, they are probably nearby in a healing tent. Recall that the hokages revived by Orochimaru were also able to sense the chakra from a far distance.

Answer (score -1):

Madara is a sensory type. He can feel a person's chakra from a continent away even before sage mode. The second was able to tell Karin's clan not only by her red hair but also by her chakra type. So Madara being a sensory type, once revived, came to his own conclusion of why he couldn't sense his clan's energy/chakra and like most of the time was right about their untimely demise.